# Workbook Closed by VBA Doesn't Close Referenced, IsAddin Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins

**Version**

Excel 2016 Desktop

**Context**

A VBA project ("client" .xlsb) has a reference to another workbook (Tools menu > References). The referenced book *isn't* an addin, it's a normal .xlsb FILE.

This has the effect that the referenced book cannot be closed if the client book is still open:

```
"This workbook is currently referenced by another workbook and cannot be closed."
```

I desire that behavior.

**Problem**

If the client book is closed by VBA using `ThisWorkbook.Close`, then the referenced book remains in memory-- it doesn't get automatically closed, as it does when the client is manually closed.

How to make the referenced book close automatically, when the Client book is closed with VBA? Ideally, the solution would close the referenced book even if other workbooks are open.

i wouldn't be able to use a solution which requires programmatically removing the reference from the client, as i can't guarantee that users have trusted access to VBA, in Macro Security.

Assume that more than one open book may reference the referenced-book, so the reference shouldn't be closed until the last client is closed.

**Attempted Solutions**

- **AfterClose event:** Let the referenced book close itself, when no other clients are open. The challenge here is that the referenced file can't be closed until after all clients are closed. Which means, we have to wait for the Workbook_AfterClose event -- unfortunately no such Workbook_AfterClose event exists. i attempted to roll my own Workbook_AfterClose event by intercepting the Application_WorkbookDeactivate and Application_WorkbookActivate events (external to the client). No luck so far.
- **OnTime:** Emulate an AfterClose event with an OnTime event 5 seconds after the last client closes. However, it appears that OnTime events aren't fired if they are registered in a Workbook_Close event that was initiated by VBA with ClientWorkbook.Close.
- **Emulate mouse:** In the client book's Workbook_Close event, emulate a mouse click on the client book's front-end close-button. But manipulating the mouse seems generally a bad idea. Also, this won't close the referenced-book if other unrelated books are open.
- **Remove reference:** Programmatically remove the reference before closing the client. But that requires trusted access to VBA, which i don't have.

Comment: Could you share the locations and the codes of the procedures that enable the described behavior?

Comment: @VBasic2008 Done.

Comment: The 'third effect' doesn't work for me i.e. the referenced workbook stays open either way. Why (how) would the referenced workbook close (when 'manually')? Please do share.

Comment: @VBasic2008 It seems i only get the third effect if there are no other files open (unrelated files, not clients to the same reference-book).

Comment: @VBasic2008 I removed info about `.IsAddin` from question. It's not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Naresh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68233204/209942), i see how to execute OnTime in a programmatic workbook close event. i improved on that method, by putting the dirty details into the external book.

This solution requires the client-book to call a custom `CloseBook` procedure, instead of `ThisWorkbook.Close` but that's not terrible.

**Client Book**

**Module 1**

```
Sub Test()
          CloseBook ThisWorkbook
End Sub
```

*Notes*

- *Reference:* If the event listener is loaded into references, then you can use the above syntax-- call `CloseBook` as if it's internal to the Client Book.
- *Addin:* If the event listener is an addin, or just another workbook, then you need to use the Run syntax:
  `Application.Run "CloseBook", ThisWorkbook`

**Event Listener Book**

**Module 1**

```
Sub CloseBook(oBk As Workbook)
          ' This is the secret sauce. 
          ' The OnTime procedure won't execute until this sub finishes, 
          ' which won't happen until oBk.Close finishes. 
          ' That's what makes this an AfterClose event. 
          Application.OnTime Now, "Workbook_AfterClose"
          oBk.Close
End Sub


Sub Workbook_AfterClose()
          ' This is the AfterClose event. Put anything you want here.
          If NoClients Then ThisWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

---

(Note, the `NoClients` procedure is outside the scope of this question)

Comment: If it works as desired you can accept your own answer. That will let others know if it works :) .. Also, not sure if [this page](https://www.excelcise.org/add-or-remove-object-library-reference-via-vba/) and this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ri8Kzwu6aqU&t=769s) (from 11:30 frame) will help in such a situation.

Comment: Thx for links, i'll check them. i have also developed the way to fire AfterClose event when user closes a workbook manually. It works for any number of open books (unlike the default behavior, which closes the referenced-book only if the client is the only open book). To include that in this answer might be off-topic, so I'm considering modifying my question to include the AfterClose code for both programmatic and user book-close events. Not sure if it's ok to mod my question. This question turned into "how to generate Workbook_AfterClose events".

Comment: @Naresh My solution eliminates need to remove refs. Removing refs programmatically requires: in Excel, select File>Options>Trust Center>Trust Center Settings>Macro Settings>Trust access to VBA Project Object Model. That can't be done programmatically. The developer could use late binding instead of References, but that's undesirable. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-do-i-get-microsoft-vba-extensibility-53  ... https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/security/en-US/57813453-9a21-4080-9d4a-e548e715d7ca/add-visual-basic-extensibility-library-through-code

Answer (score 2):

This is what you are facing

[image]

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

'~~> This is the name of the VBA project from the referenced workbook
Private Const ReferenceWbModule As String = "MyVBAProject"
Private Const ReferenceWb As String = "Test.xlsb"

Sub Sample()       
    '~~> Save the workbook (IMPORTANT)
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    
    '~~> Remove the reference
    Dim RefName As String: RefName = ReferenceWbModule
    Dim oRefS As Object, oRef As Object
    Set oRefS = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References
    For Each oRef In oRefS
        If oRef.Name = RefName Then
            oRefS.Remove oRef
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
    '~~> Close the workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks(ReferenceWb)
    wb.Close (False)
    
    '~~> Close without saving so that next time the reference is still there
    ThisWorkbook.Close (False)
End Sub
```

And this is what happens now

[image]

**NOTE**

You will have to give [Programmatic access to Office VBA project](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/programmatic-access-to-office-vba-project-is-denied-960d5265-6592-9400-31bc-b2ddfb94b445)

[image]

Else you will get the below error when you run the code.

[image]

Comment: Thx for this! i might find a solution in your design. However, i can't use your solution as-is, because i can't guarantee to have programmatic access to VBA.

Comment: Incidentally, it would only be necessary to remove the referenced-book, not all references.