# How to Fire OnTime Event by a Workbook.Close Statement?

Tags: excel, vba, ontime

It appears that if the OnTime event is registered by a programmatic MyBook.Close statement, then OnTime never runs.

This code works fine:

```
Sub TestOnTime()
          Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "MySub"
End Sub


Sub MySub()
          Debug.Print "hello"
End Sub
```

Run TestOnTime. MySub will execute, as expected.

---

And this code runs fine:

**ThisWorkbook:**

```
Dim WithEvents oApp As Application


Private Sub Workbook_Open()
          Set oApp = Application
End Sub


Private Sub oApp_WorkbookBeforeClose(ByVal Wb As Workbook, Cancel As Boolean)
          Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "MySub"
End Sub
```

**Module 1:**

```
Sub MySub()
          Debug.Print "hello"
End Sub
```

1. Manually close another workbook to fire oApp_WorkbookBeforeClose.
2. MySub executes, as expected.

---

But this code fails. The OnTime event never runs.

**Book 1**

**ThisWorkbook:**

```
Dim WithEvents oApp As Application


Private Sub Workbook_Open()
          Set oApp = Application
End Sub


Private Sub oApp_WorkbookBeforeClose(ByVal Wb As Workbook, Cancel As Boolean)
          Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "MySub"
End Sub
```

**Module 1:**

```
Sub MySub()
          Debug.Print "hello"
End Sub
```

**Book 2**

**Module 1:**

```
Sub Test()
          ThisWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

1. Run `Test` to close Book 2.
2. Book 1 oApp_WorkbookBeforeClose
   executes, as expected.
3. But the Book 1 MySub event never runs.

***Why?***

Why doesn't OnTime execute if registered by a Workbook_BeforeClose event? No code is running in the book that's closing. OnTime works no problem with other events (eg programmatically opening a workbook). Somehow, closing a workbook *programmatically* breaks OnTime. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Book 2 is being closed, You should include the Application.OnTime procedure in Book 2 and not in Book 1

Also, I think those books should be saved once and not new books.

```
Sub test()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "Book 1.xlsm!MySub"
ThisWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

**EDIT Jul 6 -**

You are closing the workbook and then you are trying to run a macro `MySub` in the same workbook after 5 seconds. Macro in the same workbook will not run once the book is closed. Application will reopen the file to run the macro. If you want to close Book2 after 5 seconds of closing `Thisworkbook` then --

in Thisworkbook

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "Book2.xlsm!Test"
End Sub
```

So, after closing `Thisworkbook`, macro named "Test" in Book2 will run and will close that workbook.

Comment: You have already posted this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68217359/workbook-closed-by-vba-doesnt-close-referenced-isaddin-workbook) in a different way. I would still suggest if you are programmatically closing the client.xlsb then try closing the addin book first in the same procedure in client.xls

Comment: This question is about one possible solution to the other question. I believe it's not possible to close the addin book first: "This workbook is currently referenced by another workbook and cannot be closed."

Comment: @johnywhy May be you have to remove the reference first in client.xlsb and then close the addin and then close client.xlsb all programmatically .

Comment: It's not possible to programmatically remove references without trusted access to VBA, which can only be done manually. We can't do that.

Comment: i improved on your answer here, to make a solution to the other question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68236858/209942

Comment: Why, tho', doesn't the OnTime execute? OnTime works with other events no problem (eg Workbook_Open)  Somehow, closing a workbook breaks OnTime.

Comment: Didn't understand your edit. In my OP, no code is running in the book that's closing.

Comment: In `Thisworkbook` you are using the event `oApp_WorkbookBeforeClose` and in the same workbook `Module1` you are trying to run `MySub` 5 seconds after `Thisworkbook` is closed with `Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "MySub"` .. So `MySub` will not run once `ThisWorkbook` is closed. Instead of referring to `MySub` in `OnTime` statement you can refer to some macro in other open workbook or addin. But for that also to be executed, excel needs to be running

Comment: i think you're describing what i'm doing in my solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68236858/209942

Comment: True. But in the solution i linked, the sub called by OnTime isn't in the workbook being closed. Thx!

Comment: Oh you want me to see the other link? I will check it.

Comment: "I think those books should be saved" -- i haven't found it necessary to save the closing book for your wrapper to work. Works fine with new, never-saved books.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234616/discussion-between-naresh-and-johny-why).